# How can I enhance the speed of massive INSERT in ADO.NET?

Tags: .net, system.data.sqlite, advantage-database-server

I downloaded a trial of  Advanced Database Server (ADS) 10.1, together with ARC and ADO.NET provider. My main intention was to know the performance of massive INSERTS from  millions of records compared to SQLite .NET (http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).

In ADS, 7 millions entries were loaded in 30 minutes.

In Sqlite for.NET, the same 7 millions entries were loaded in less than 3 minutes!!

Why? What can I do to enhance the speed in ADS with the .NET provider?

Regards .

## EDIT

Thanks for your recommendations, In ADS code I mistakenly included the creation of some indexes, when I suppressed this, the loading elapsed time was 10 minutes.

Let me add some example code and sample data (which you can multiply until getting 7 million entries). If you can find ways to enhance and optimize performance, please let me know.

CODE FOR SYBASE ADS:

```
 public void LoadAds(string opt, string file)
    {
        AdsConnection conn = new AdsConnection(@"data source=C:\apps\dataApps\cmpExistenc\inv.ads;" +
            "ServerType=local; TableType=ADT");
        conn.Open();
        var stV = new st();
        var dicTxt = new Dictionary<object, st>();
        if (opt.ToUpper() == "C")
        {
            using (AdsCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE lbl; DROP TABLE almlbl";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch { }
                cmd.CommandText =
                    "CREATE TABLE lbl (alm varchar(4), alm2 varchar(4), " +
                       "mat varchar(18), ser varchar(20), fac varchar(18), almlbl varchar(10), " +
                       "cant integer, sts varchar(1), ser_2_20 varchar(20), rowid_sap integer, stsmat varchar(100));";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.CommandText =
                    "CREATE TABLE almlbl (almlbl varchar(10), almlbltxt varchar(100), " +
                       "ciudad varchar(50));";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        else
            using (AdsCommand cmdTxt = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmdTxt.CommandText = "SELECT * from almlbl";
                AdsDataReader drT = cmdTxt.ExecuteReader();
                while (drT.Read())
                    dicTxt[drT[0]] = new st() { almlblTxt = drT[1], ciudad = drT[2] };
                drT.Dispose();
                cmdTxt.CommandText = "DELETE FROM almlbl";
                cmdTxt.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


        using (AdsTransaction transac = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            AdsCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Transaction = transac;
            AdsParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
            cmd = LibCorp.Ads.buildParmsFromTable("lbl", conn, transac);
            long regLei = 0;
            List<object> cols;
            try
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default);
                sr.ReadLine(); // Ignore title
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if ((++regLei % 1000000) == 0)
                        o.show(string.Format(" lbl:{0}", regLei), tbx);
                    cols = new List<object>(line.Split('|'));
                    if (!dicTxt.ContainsKey((string)cols[5]))
                    {
                        stV.almlblTxt = cols[6];
                        stV.ciudad = cols[8];
                        dicTxt[cols[5]] = stV;
                    }
                    if (!cols[3].Equals("") && cols[3].ToString().Length > 18)
                        cols.Add(cols[3].ToString().Substring(1));
                    else
                        cols.Add(DBNull.Value);

                    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = cols[0];       // alm
                    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = cols[1];       // alm2
                    cmd.Parameters[2].Value = cols[2];       // mat
                    cmd.Parameters[3].Value = cols[3];       // ser
                    cmd.Parameters[4].Value = cols[4];       // fac
                    cmd.Parameters[5].Value = cols[5];       // almlbl
                    cmd.Parameters[6].Value = cols[7];       // cant
                    cmd.Parameters[7].Value = DBNull.Value;  // sts
                    cmd.Parameters[8].Value = cols[10];      // ser_2_20
                    cmd.Parameters[9].Value = DBNull.Value;  // rowid_sap
                    cmd.Parameters[10].Value = cols[9];      // stsmat
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                foreach (KeyValuePair<object, st> pair in dicTxt)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO almlbl VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}')",
                            pair.Key, pair.Value.almlblTxt, pair.Value.ciudad);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                transac.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                o.notify(string.Format("{0}\n\rSitio->{1}", ex, ex.TargetSite.Name));
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

CODE FOR SQLITE FOR .NET:

```
public void LoadSQLITE(string opt, string file)
    {
        conn = new SQLiteConnection
            (@"Data Source=inv.db3; Page Size=65536; Cache Size=65536; Synchronous=Off; Journal Mode=Off;");
        conn.Open();
        var stV = new st();
        var dicTxt = new Dictionary<object, st>(); // faster than SortedDictionary
        if (opt.ToUpper() == "C")
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE lbl; DROP TABLE almlbl";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch { }
                cmd.CommandText =
                    "CREATE TABLE lbl (alm varchar(4), alm2 varchar(4), " +
                       "mat varchar(18), ser varchar(20), fac varchar(18), almlbl varchar(10), " +
                       "cant integer, sts varchar(1), ser_2_20 varchar(20), rowid_sap integer, stsmat varchar);" +
                    "CREATE TABLE almlbl (almlbl varchar(10), almlbltxt varchar(100), " +
                       "ciudad varchar(50));"; //+
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        else
            using (SQLiteCommand cmdTxt = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
            {
                cmdTxt.CommandText = "SELECT * from almlbl";
                SQLiteDataReader drT = cmdTxt.ExecuteReader();
                while (drT.Read())
                    dicTxt[drT[0]] = new st() { almlblTxt = drT[1], ciudad = drT[2] };
                drT.Dispose();
                cmdTxt.CommandText = "DELETE FROM almlbl";
                cmdTxt.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        using (SQLiteTransaction transac = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
            {
                SQLiteParameter param = new SQLiteParameter();
                SQLiteCommand cmdAux = LibCorp.Lite.buildParmsFromTable("lbl", conn);
                cmd.CommandText = cmdAux.CommandText;
                foreach (SQLiteParameter sp in cmdAux.Parameters)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(sp);
                long regLei = 0;
                try
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default);
                    sr.ReadLine(); // Ignore title
                    List<object> cols;
                    string line;
                    while (!string.Equals(line = sr.ReadLine(), null)) // Fastest way
                    {
                        if ((++regLei % 1000000) == 0)  //Diff of only 1 or 2 secs if omitted
                            o.show(string.Format(" lbl:{0}", regLei), tbx);
                        cols = new List<object>(line.Split('|')); // Fastest way
                        if (!dicTxt.ContainsKey((string)cols[5])) // diff of only 1 sec if commented
                        {
                            stV.almlblTxt = cols[6];
                            stV.ciudad = cols[8];
                            dicTxt[cols[5]] = stV;
                        }

                        if (!cols[3].Equals("") && cols[3].ToString().Length > 18)
                            cols.Add(cols[3].ToString().Substring(1));
                        else
                            cols.Add(DBNull.Value);

                        cmd.Parameters[0].Value = cols[0];       // alm
                        cmd.Parameters[1].Value = cols[1];       // alm2
                        cmd.Parameters[2].Value = cols[2];       // mat
                        cmd.Parameters[3].Value = cols[3];       // ser
                        cmd.Parameters[4].Value = cols[4];       // fac
                        cmd.Parameters[5].Value = cols[5];       // almlbl
                        cmd.Parameters[6].Value = cols[7];       // cant
                        cmd.Parameters[7].Value = DBNull.Value;  // sts
                        cmd.Parameters[8].Value = cols[10];      // ser_2_20
                        cmd.Parameters[9].Value = DBNull.Value;  // rowid_sap
                        cmd.Parameters[10].Value = cols[9];      // stsmat
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<object, st> pair in dicTxt)
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO almlbl VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}')",
                                pair.Key, pair.Value.almlblTxt, pair.Value.ciudad);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    transac.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    o.notify(string.Format("{0}\n\rSitio->{1}", ex, ex.TargetSite.Name));
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

AND SOME DATA FOR TESTING (MULTIPLY UNTIL 7 MILLIONS, PLEASE INCLUDE TITLE LINE):

```
COD_ALMACEN_SAP|COD_ALMACEN_SAP2|CODIGO_SAP|NRO_SERIE_INICIAL|NRO_INICIO_FACTURA|COD_ALMACEN|NOMBRE_ALMACEN|CANTIDAD|CIUDAD|NOMBRE_ARTICULO
```

1030|8030|ADAJKIUSD66K|||16|ALMACEN DANSA PRUZ TESULARES|4|BANDA PRUZ|ADA-KI-SD66K ADAPTADOR MAIDIUM SD-66K
1030|8030|BAT-KI-BPA101|||16|ALMACEN LANTA CRUZ TESULARES|5|BANDA PRUZ|BAT-KI-BPA101 BATERIESAPS
1020|8020|TARGESA/P_PC-GC79|||17|PERRITORIAL CENTER|9|POCHASALTA|TARGESA/P_PC-GC79 TARGESA UNIVERSAL P PC GPRS Y WL
1010|8010|TARJETA/P_PC-GC79|||1014|TERRITORIES NORTH 1|5|PATPAZ|TARGESA/P_PC-GC79 TARJETA UNIVERSAL P PC GPRS Y WL
1060|8060|TARJETA/P_PC-GC79|||1095|ALMACEN SUNY|1|TRONOSAD|TARGESA/P_PC-GC79 TARGESA UNIVERSAL P PC GPRS Y WL

```
enter code here
```

Regards.

Regards.

Comment: Hello Juliet, I posted the code.

Comment: One thing worth trying is to limit the size of the transaction. I have seen one example where a large change was so big that it took ages to write a huge entry the transaction log. (not posted as answer because this is hearsay).

Comment: Jan, many thanks for your comments, as you can see Sqlite and ADS are suject to the same code conditions but Sqlite is the fastest by far (in bulk insert at least). I would like to know how I can limit the size of transaction, using a counter in my program? Regards.

Answer (score 2):

First of all ensure, that in both cases you are using transaction and query is the same. 2nd ensure, that you're calling the Insert query in the same way - do not create redundant (for every Insert call) connection, query or adapter object in one case but not in other. The difference is too ... significant.

Comment: That said, isn#t SQL Lite embedded, the othe a server (which means calls go through a network layer)? I would suggest parallelizing the inserts on 10-20 threads.

Comment: Hello TomTom, I configured for 20 threads, but no important enhancement exists, the average time keeps in 2 minutes per 1 million entries inserted.

Comment: UGEEN, I included the code for both, Sybase and .NET Sqlite; the code that I run in a PC is very similar but .NET Sqlite is faster that Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the transaction. ADS transactions are different than traditional RDBMS and require more OS flush operations (ADS doesn't use checkpoints). Performance will be way better without the transaction.

**Edit** Noticed you are using local server, so my comments about the transaction will not be relevant. Dang!

Also, I don't know how many loops are involved in the second loop (INSERT INTO almlbl), but changing to a prepared query with params would help.

It's fairly likely that all of those SQLite rows are not on disk yet. I would assume quite a few are in memory and haven't been flushed.

Comment: Jeremy, many thanks for your answer, table almlbl es very,very small compared to lbl. As you can see both Sqlite and ADS are under the same code conditions and load the same amount of records. I suppose that ADS tries to be safe in not loosing data so it takes a little longer to load (7 million records in 5 o 6  minutes more than Sqlite), however I never had problems with Sqlite. Regards.